# How to get more than 100 contacts from Microsoft's ExchangeService ResolveName method

Tags: c#, exchange-server

How to get more than 100 contacts from Microsoft's ExchangeService ResolveName method ?

I am using the below code

```
var nameResolutionCollection = serviceData.ResolveName("SMTP:")
```

This is returning only 100 records even though more contact are there in global contact list .

Is there any way to get more than 100 records ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: As per this link, you cannot execute this command in batch and hence no direct method. But it has an alternative. Check https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d61ea2e2-159b-4ca8-9107-ab84c9cdeb44/how-to-do-exchangeserviceresolvename-for-a-batch-of-smtp-addresses?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

See this documentation on [ResolveNames operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563518%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

apparently, 100 is the max limit

Comment: no workaround  solution to get more than 100 record ?